# How does Exception class know about the ArithmeticException class?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have read that superclass object can point to subclass object but does not know about the content of subclass .
Then how can superclass can catch exception of type subclass ?

I am confused here . Please someone help

```
class abc {
    public static void main(String k[]) {
        try {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 56 / 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" divide by zero ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArithmeticException` is a subtype of `Exception`. So, in your `catch`, what you're saying is "catch everything that is `Exception` or a subtype of `Exception`. In this case, that includes `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

These are two independent things. 
1st case is that a generic type will not have visibility of the specific type. the second is reverse, where the exception is matched with he specific type and if not found, goes up the class hierarchy to find the next generic type and the next one until one matches.

in this specific scenario, AE is a subclass of E and hence if you don't have AE, it matches to the next generic type up the hierarchy , which is Exception

Answer (score 0):

A superclass doesn't know about it's subclasses. It's the other way around, i.e. a subclass knows about it's direct superclass.

Your `catch` statement is kind of like an `if` statement with an `instanceof` operator:

```
if (thrownException instanceof Exception) {
    Exception e = (Exception) thrownException;
    System.out.pritnln("divide by zero");
}
```

The `instanceof` operator is logically done by getting the class of the object on the left side and checking if it, or any of it's superclasses, is the class on the right side of the operator.

So, as you can see, it's not `Exception` that knows about `ArithmeticException`, it's `ArithmeticException` that knows about `Exception`, in order for that `catch` statement to work.